# How to display all results in php mysql in recursive function

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

i want to display some result using recursion
first here is my table structure

```
contactid       name        reportsto
 244797          ankit         9876
 438             Mukti         244797
 445             Moorthy       244797
 446             P K Roy       244797
 448             Suruchi       438
 542             Lalit Kumar   438
 543             Balkrishan    542
```

when i print_r($printres) then i receive only id whose reported to 244797 please check my code and evaluate my problem thanks.

Comment: Unlike some other RDBMS, MySQL doesn't support recursive functions—which makes it poorly suited to this "adjacency list" model of storing hierarchical data (you must explicitly self-join for each level of depth you desire); consider instead redesigning your schema to use either the "nested sets" or "transitive closure" models, about which you can learn more from [@Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin)'s excellent presentation [Models for Hierarchical Data in SQL and PHP](https://youtu.be/wuH5OoPC3hA).

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect example but i hope this will get you started. That will look something like this:

```
function recursive($reportsTo){
    //make some logic that if contactid == reportsto does something (make table or layout)
    recursive($contactId)
}

recursive(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this query will help. You try this.

```
   select contactid,name,'' level2,'' as level3, 0 ord,0 ord1,0 ord2 from tablename where reportsto=0 union select LW1.contactid,'' as name,LW.name level2,'' as level3,1 ord,LW.mid ord1,0 ord2 from tablename LW, tablename LW1 where  LW.reportsto=LW1.contactid and LW.reportsto in(select contactid from tablename where reportsto=0) union select LW2.contactid,'' as name,'' as level2,LW.name as level3,1 ord,LW.reportsto ord1,1 ord2 from tablename LW,tablename tablename LW2  where LW.reportsto=LW1.contactid and LW1.reportsto=LW2.contactid and LW.reportsto in(select reportsto from iman_module where reportsto<>0) order by contactid,ord,ord1,ord2
```